# If every proper subgroup of a nonabelian group is abelian, why must the group be generated by two elements?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

In my group theory class our teacher gave us this statement but I don't understand exactly why it's true.

> Let  $G$ be a non-abelian group such that every proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian, we can find $a$, $b\in G$ that satisfy:
>   $$G=\langle a,b \rangle$$

Comment: I always find it odd when a question is interesting enough to admit a +14 answer, but not interesting enough to get many votes itself.

Comment: @user1729 I agree. I think the question was on the hot question list, which might explain the upvotes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $G$ is nonabelian you can find two elements $a$ and $b$ that don't commute. They generate some subgroup that's not abelian. If all the proper subgroups are abelian then that one must be the whole group.